# MPI_Isend /Irecv: Is it possible to access the sendbuffer on unused memory-locations in the meanwhile

Tags: mpi, memory-access

I would like to speedup my MPI- Program with the use of asynchronous communication. But the used time remains the same. The workflow is as followed.

```
before:
1.  MPI_send/ MPI_recv Halo           (ca. 10 Seconds) 
2.  process the whole Array           (ca. 12 Seconds)

after:
1. MPI_Isend/ MPI_Irecv Halo         (ca. 0,1 Seconds)
2. process the Array (without Halo)  (ca. 10 Seconds)
3. MPI_Wait                          (ca. 10 Seconds)  (should be ca. 0 Seconds)
4. process the Halo only             (ca. 2 Seconds)
```

Measurements showed that the communication and processing the Array-core nearly take the same time for common workloads. So asynchronism should nearly hide the communication time.
But it dosn't.

One fact - and I thinks this could be the problem - is that the sendbuffer is also the array the calculations are made on. Is it possible that MPI serializes the memory-access although communication ONLY accesses the Halo (with derived datatype) and the computation ONLY accesses the core (only reading) of the array???

Does anybody know if this is for sure the reason?

Is it maybe implementation-dependend (I'm using OpenMPI)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the message is large enough so that it cannot be buffered internally by the MPI implementation, then the latter would not start sending the message until the receiver has posted a matching receive. Could you post part of your code?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the case that MPI serializes the memory accesses in the user code (that's beyond the library's power to do, in general), and it is true that what exactly does happen is implementation specific.

But as a practical matter, MPI libraries don't do as much communication "in the background" as you might hope, and this is particularly true when using transports and networks like tcp + ethernet, where there's no meaningful way to hand off communication to another set of hardware.

You can only be sure that the MPI library is actually doing something when you're running MPI library code, eg in an MPI function call.   Often, a call to any of a number of MPI calls will  nudge an implementations "progress engine" that keeps track of in-flight messages and ushers them along.  So for instance one thing you can quickly do is to make calls to MPI_Test() on the requests within the compute loop to make sure things start happening well before the MPI_Wait().   There is of course overhead to this, but this is something that's easy to try to measure.

Of course you could imagine the MPI library would use some other mechanism to run things behind the scenes.  Both MPICH2 and OpenMPI have played with separate "progress threads" which execute separately from the user code and do this ushering along in the background; but getting that to work well, and without tying up a processor while you're trying to run your computation, is a genuinely difficult problem.   OpenMPI's progress threads implementation has long been experimental, and in fact is temporarily out of the current (1.6.x) release, although work continues.  I'm not sure about MPICH2's support.

If you are using infiniband, where the network hardware has a lot of intelligence to it, then prospects brighten a bit.   If you are willing to leave memory pinned (for the openfabrics), and/or you can use a vendor-specific module (mxm for Mellanox, psm for Qlogic), then things can progress somewhat more rapidly.   If you're using shared memory, than the [knem kernel module](http://runtime.bordeaux.inria.fr/knem/) can also help with intranode transport.

One other implementation-specific approach you can take, if memory isn't a big issue, is to try to use [eager protocols](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi_performance/#Protocols) for sending the data directly, or send more data per chunk so fewer nudges of the progress engine are needed.  What eager protocols means here is that data is automatically sent at send time, rather than just initiating a set of handshakes which will eventually lead to the message being sent.  The bad news is that this generally requires extra buffer memory for the library, but if that's not a problem and you know the number of incoming messages is bounded (eg, by the number of halo neighbours you have), this can help a great deal.   How to do this for (eg) shared memory transport for openmpi is described on [the OpenMPI page for tuning for shared memory](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=sm#more-sm), but similar parameters exist for other transports and often for other implementations.  One nice tool that [IntelMPI](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mpi-library/) has is an "mpitune" tool that automatically runs through a number of such parameters for best performance.

Answer (score 0):

The [MPI specification](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report.pdf) states:

> A nonblocking send call indicates that the system may start copying
>   data out of the send buffer. The sender should not modify any part of the
>   send buffer after a nonblocking send operation is called, until the
>   send completes.

So yes, you should copy your data to a dedicated send buffer first.

Comment: Yes, but you're allowed to *read* the send buffer, which is probably what the OP is doing for the halos.

Comment: Right! While the communication is running my computation only reads from sendbuffer and even not on the same locations.